# How does it seem to appear that another thread is able to acquire the lock while one thread having the same lock is sleeping?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Below code - without the wait() and notify() methods:

```
package com.jay;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Message message = new Message();
        (new Thread(new Writer(message))).start();
        (new Thread(new Reader(message))).start();
    }

}

class Message {
    private String message;
    private boolean empty = true;

    public synchronized String read() {
        while (empty) {

        }
        empty = true;
        return message;
    }

    public synchronized void write(String message) {
        while (!empty) {

        }
        empty = false;
        this.message = message;
    }
}

class Writer implements Runnable {
    private Message message;

    public Writer(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void run() {
        String[] messages = {
            "Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall",
            "Humpty Dumpty had a great fall",
            "All the king's horses and all the king's men",
            "Couldn't put Humpty together again"
        };

        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i=0; i<messages.length; i++) {
            message.write(messages[i]);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(2000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
        message.write("Finished");
    }
}

class Reader implements Runnable {
    private Message message;

    public Reader(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void run() {
        Random random = new Random();

        for(String latestMessage = message.read(); !latestMessage.equals("Finished"); 
                latestMessage = message.read()) {
            System.out.println(latestMessage);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(2000));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It prints below on the console - most of the times and hangs:

```
Humpty Dumpty sat on a wall

Humpty Dumpty had a great fall
```

and some times it prints all the four messages.

My question is: How is Reader thread able to execute the code in read() method while the Writer thread already has the lock acquired and still looping?

I am confused. Please help me understand!

Comment: By "lock" you mean the fact that the methods on `Message` are synchronized, right?  Note that the reader can enter a synchronized method every time the writer leaves a synchronized method.  i.e. in-between method calls.

Comment: Oh man! How could I miss this?! `Note that the reader can enter a synchronized method every time the writer leaves a synchronized method. i.e. in-between method calls.`

This answered my doubts. I somehow failed to notice that the lock is released after the method executes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

@Oliver Charlesworth's comment cleared my doubts. I failed to notice that the reader can enter a synchronized method every time the writer leaves a synchronized method. The program hangs because there will be stage where in one thread will be sleeping and the value of the "empty" field won't get modified, resulting in one of the loops running infinitely. Once the wait() and notify() methods get implemented, the problem will get solved!